# Ignoring noncharacters in cypher text

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a simple ROT algorithm that loops through the values in a string and shifts characters by 13 letters. I'm having trouble making the algorithm ignore spaces, numbers and other non letter characters. How would I go about implementing that feature?

Here is the code so far:

```
phrase = raw_input("Please enter plaintext to Cipher: ")
shift = 13

result = ''
for char in phrase:
    x = ord(char) 
    if char.isalpha():
        x = x + shift
        offset = 65
        if char.islower():
            offset = 97

        while x < offset:
            x += 26

        while x > offset+25:
            x -= 26

    result += chr(x)

print result
```

Comment: Your code works for me. isalpha() does the check correctly. Can you provide an example of a failure?

Comment: I wrote something like this years ago.  Your article inspired me to pull it out of an old backup and add it to my SVN repo: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/rot13/trunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
phrase = "".join(c for c in phrase if c.isalpha())
```

Then you deal only with the upper- and lower-case letters. If you want the punctuation kept, remove it:

```
punct = [(i, c) for i, c in enumerate(phrase) if not c.isalpha()]
```

Then put it back when you're finished:

```
phrase = list(phrase)
for i, c in punct:
    phrase.insert(i, c)
phrase = "".join(phrase)
```

Or, when iterating over the chars, what you have should work correctly:

```
for char in phrase:
    if char.isalpha():
        # process
    else:
        pass # ignore spaces, punctuation, numbers
```

Comment: Would I implement that after phrase=raw_input?

Comment: Yes, use this to process the string the user enters

Comment: I tried it and it's still just ignoring non alpha characters. I'm putting it before the loop. Where should it be placed?

Comment: I thought you *wanted* the algorithm to ignore them?